# Create checkerboard distribution with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create a checkerboard distribution in Python.

Currently I use the following script to create a `2 x 2` sized checkerboard:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_points = 1000
n_classes = 2

x = np.random.uniform(-1,1, size=(n_points, n_classes))
mask = np.logical_or(np.logical_and(x[:,0] > 0.0, x[:,1] > 0.0), \
np.logical_and(x[:,0] < 0.0, x[:,1] < 0.0))
y = np.eye(n_classes)[1*mask]

plt.scatter(x[:,0], x[:,1], c=y[:,0], cmap="bwr", alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

which creates

[image]

I would like to know if there exists a simple way to generalize the above code to create a checkerboard distribution of size `n x n`?

**EDIT**

Using @jpf's great solution

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import sin

n_points = 10000
n_classes = 2
n = 8

x = np.random.uniform(-(n//2)*np.pi, (n//2)*np.pi, size=(n_points, n_classes))
mask = np.logical_or(np.logical_and(sin(x[:,0]) > 0.0, sin(x[:,1]) > 0.0), \
np.logical_and(sin(x[:,0]) < 0.0, sin(x[:,1]) < 0.0))
y = np.eye(n_classes)[1*mask]

plt.scatter(x[:,0], x[:,1], c=y[:,0], s=1, cmap="bwr", alpha=0.5)
plt.savefig("test.png", dpi=150)
plt.show()
```

I can now generate checkerboard distributions of arbitrary size:

[image]

Comment: What's the use of the `mask_1` variable?

Comment: @rassar Good point! `mask_1` it not used. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using a periodic function like sine?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import sin

n_points = 10000
n_classes = 2

x = np.random.uniform(-10,10, size=(n_points, n_classes))
mask = np.logical_or(np.logical_and(sin(x[:,0]) > 0.0, sin(x[:,1]) > 0.0), \
np.logical_and(sin(x[:,0]) < 0.0, sin(x[:,1]) < 0.0))
y = np.eye(n_classes)[1*mask]

plt.scatter(x[:,0], x[:,1], c=y[:,0], cmap="bwr", alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Using the sine to mask the array is an excellent idea, but then to make it generic (any `n x n`) you need to control the frequency of the `sin` function. You are still not doing that.

Comment: Great approach. Instead of `np.random.uniform(-10,10, size=(n_points, n_classes))` we can use something like `np.random.uniform(-n*np.pi,n*np.pi, size=(n_points, n_classes))` to have perfect borders. Where `n` is a natural number.